# c++ protobuf: how to iterate through fields of message?

Tags: c++, iteration, protocols, protocol-buffers

I'm new to protobuf and I'm stuck with simple task: I need to iterate through fields of message and check it's type. If type is message I will do same recursively for this message.

For example, I have such messages:

```
package MyTool;

message Configuration {
    required GloablSettings         globalSettings  = 1;
    optional string                 option1         = 2;
    optional int32                  option2         = 3;
    optional bool                   option3         = 4;

}

message GloablSettings {
    required bool                   option1         = 1;
    required bool                   option2         = 2;
    required bool                   option3         = 3;
}
```

Now, to explicitly access a field value in C++ I can do this:

```
MyTool::Configuration config;
fstream input("config", ios::in | ios::binary);
config.ParseFromIstream(&input);

bool option1val = config.globalSettings().option1();
bool option2val = config.globalSettings().option2();
```

and so on. This approach is not convenient in case when have big amount of fields.

Can I do this with iteration and get field's name and type? I know there are *descriptors* of type and somewhat called *reflection*, but I didn't have success in my attempts.
Can some one give me example of code if it's possible?

Thanks!

Comment: For anybody interested in Java version, here is the link:
https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/245224902a80d489389df192c0990ff70f2f3e4c/java/src/main/java/com/google/protobuf/TextFormat.java#L294

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at how the Protobuf library implements the `TextFormat::Printer` class, which uses descriptors and reflection to iterate over fields and convert them to text:

https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc#L1473

Comment: The file must have changed... can you pin that link to a particular commit? Today, that line you have referenced reads `FORWARD_IMPL(PrintString, val);` which isn't terribly helpful.

Comment: Look for the class `TextFormat::Printer`. Looks like it's now declared in the header and defined in the .cc. https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/text_format.h#L181

Answer (score 30):

This is old but maybe someone will benefit. Here is a method that prints the contents of a protobuf message:

```
 void Example::printMessageContents(std::shared_ptr<google::protobuf::Message> m)
 {
      const Descriptor *desc       = m->GetDescriptor();
      const Reflection *refl       = m->GetReflection();   
      int fieldCount= desc->field_count();
      fprintf(stderr, "The fullname of the message is %s \n", desc->full_name().c_str());
      for(int i=0;i<fieldCount;i++)
      {
        const FieldDescriptor *field = desc->field(i);
        fprintf(stderr, "The name of the %i th element is %s and the type is  %s \n",i,field->name().c_str(),field->type_name());
      }
 }
```

You can find in [FieldDescriptor Enum Values](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection) the possible values you get from `field->type`. For example for the message type you would have to check if type is equal to `FieldDescriptor::TYPE_MESSAGE`.

This  function prints all the "metadata" of the protobuf message. However you need to check separately for each value what the type is and then  call the corresponding getter function using [Reflection](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message#Reflection).

So using this condition we could extract the strings :

```
 if(field->type() == FieldDescriptor::TYPE_STRING  && !field->is_repeated())
      {
            std::string g= refl->GetString(*m, field);
            fprintf(stderr, "The value is %s ",g.c_str());
      }
```

However fields can be either repeated or not repeated and different methods are used for both field types. So a check is used here to assure that we are using the right method. For repeated fields we have for example this method for strings :

`GetRepeatedString(const Message & message, const FieldDescriptor * field, int index`)

So it takes the index of the repeated field into consideration.

In the case of FieldDescriptor of type Message, the function provided will only print the name of the message, we better print its contents too.

```
      if(field->type()==FieldDescriptor::TYPE_MESSAGE)
       {
         if(!field->is_repeated())  
         {
           const Message &mfield = refl->GetMessage(*m, field);      
           Message *mcopy = mfield.New();
           mcopy->CopyFrom(mfield);
           void *ptr = new std::shared_ptr<Message>(mcopy);
           std::shared_ptr<Message> *m =
           static_cast<std::shared_ptr<Message> *>(ptr);
           printMessageContents(*m);
          }
       }
```

And finally if the field is repeated you will have to call the `FieldSize` method on the reflection and iterate all repeated fields.